# Pandas: comparação de informações em DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho 2 DataFrames importados de CSV

CSV1

```
4616; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4616.htm
4617; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4617.htm
4618; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4618.htm
4619; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4619.htm
4620; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4620.htm
4620impressao; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4620impressao.htm
4621; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4621.htm
4622; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4622.htm
4623; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4623.htm
4624; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4624.htm
4625; CCIVIL_03/decreto/2003/D4625.htm
```

CSV2

```
04456; 2002; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2002/D04456.html
05931; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05931.html
05940; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05940.html
05922; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05922.html
05933; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05933.html
05934; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05934.html
05937; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05937.html
05921; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05921.html
05932; 2006; CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/2006/D05932.html
```

Segue o código implementado:

```
import pandas as pd
df_acervo1 = pd.read_csv('../atos_publicados_dec_url_num.csv', sep=';', names=['num', 'url'])
df_acervo3 = pd.read_csv('../atos_publicados_dec_sican_url_num_ano.csv', sep=';',
                         names=['num', 'ano', 'url'])
```

Como posso associar os dois CSV, onde há correspondência de numeração? desta forma:

```
num, ano, url_CSV1, url_CSV2
2204, 1985, CCIVIL_03/decreto/1851-1899/D02204.html,  CCIVIL_03/Atos/decretos/1895/D02204.html
```

Comment: O que seria "correspondência de numeração"? O seu exemplo final possui o ano 1985, mas ele não aparece em nenhum dos dois CSVs; de onde ele surgiu?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss. Correspondencia de numeração seria num_CSV1 = num_CSV2, e ano pertence a CSV2; o exemplo final é uma expectativa de resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brito, nesse caso voce pode utilizar a função do Pandas - **Merge**

o código deve ser:

```
df_join = pd.merge(df_acervo1, df_acervo3, how ='inner', on = ['num'])
```

Obs. O parâmetro **ON** que está acima representa a chave entre as duas colunas

Obs2. No parâmetro **HOW** voce tera de colocar o tipo de join que deseja da mesma forma que no banco de dados (RIGHT, LEFT, INNER)